# How to retrieve data from models in table with a month days as table heads?

Tags: django, python-3.x

Am new to Django, am trying to retrieve data from the models into html table. Essentially, I want to retrieve all teachers and their attendance Status(Present, Absent and Late ) in a particular month that the user selects.
Am able to pass the context to the template from the views
here is my code

**models.py**

```
class TeacherAttendance(models.Model):
teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=True)
date = models.DateField()
status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ATTENDANCE)
objects = models.Manager()

class Meta:
    default_permissions = ('view', 'add', 'change', 'delete')
    ordering = ["date", ]
    get_latest_by = "date"
```

**views.py**

```
def teacher_attendance_report(request):
context = {}
form = TeacherAttendanceForm(request.POST)
if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.POST.get('group_by'):
        grab_data_passed = request.POST.get('group_by')
        get_details = TeacherAttendance.objects.filter(date__month=grab_data_passed)
        z=0
        range=9
        days=[]
        if z< range:
            dats = TeacherAttendance.objects.filter(date__month=grab_data_passed)[z].date
            z+=1
            y=dats.month
            x=dats.year
            cal = calendar.TextCalendar(calendar.WEDNESDAY)
            for day in cal.itermonthdays(x, y):
               days.append(day) 
        context['days']=days
        teacher = User.objects.filter(is_teacher=True)
        for i in teacher:
            x=i.id
            get_details = TeacherAttendance.objects.filter(teacher__user=x, date__month=grab_data_passed)
        context['get_details']=get_details  
        return render(request, 'Reports/teacher_attendance_report_details.html', context)
context={'form':form}
return render(request, 'Reports/teacher_attendance_report_index.html', context)
```

I don't know whether that's the best pythonic way of retrieving data in a view function.

here is my

**template**

```
 <table id="datatable-responsive"
                           class="datatable-responsive table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                         <tr>   
                        <th>Teacher <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down" z></i> - Date <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></th>
                            <th>{{days}}</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {% for details in get_details %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ details.teacher }}</td>
                                <td>{{ details.status }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            {% if empty %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="9" class="text-center bg-warning">No Data</td>
                                </tr>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Currently this is what I am getting in the browser
[image: current table]

I want to achieve something similar to
[image: this]

Any advice or code restructuring to achieve desired target is well come, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know its too late to answer this question,
But i was recently creating a attendance system for employees. I needed exactly this thing. after searching the internet i did not found any suitable thing.
so i created a custom template filter which takes the user and date as argument and return the attendance of that date

here is the code:

````
@register.filter(name='gmd')
def get_attendance(user,date):
    a =  Attendance.objects.filter(user=user,attendance__date=date).values_list('attendance',flat=True)
    if a:
        if a.count() > 1:
            l = ''
            for i in a:
                l += (i.strftime('%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S %p')) + '\n'
            return l
        else:
            l = list(a)[0]

            return l.strftime('%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S %p')
    return '--' 
Template File:

{% load attendance_extras %}
{% block content %}
<h1 class='text-center m-2'>Attendance Record of Month {{month}}</h1>
<div class="table-responsive">
<table  class="table table-hover table-dark table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Employee Name</th>
      {% for date in days_list %}
      <th scope="col" class ='text-center' name="{{date|date:'d-m-Y'}}">
        {{date|date:'d/m/Y'}}
      </th>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for user in users %}
    <tr>
      <th  class ='text-center' name="{{user}}" scope="row">{{user}}</th>
      {% for date in days_list  %}
        
        <td >{{ user|gmd:date|linebreaks }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>

</div>
{% endblock content %} ```
````

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<th>{% for day in days %}{{day}}{% endfor %}</th>
```

instead of

```
<th>{{days}}</th>
```

after that you need to send teachers list to context in view
something like

```
teacher = User.objects.filter(is_teacher=True)
context['teachers'] = teacher
```

and then in your html try

```
<tbody>
   {% for teacher in teachers %}
     <tr>
       <td>{{ teacher }}</td>
       {% for details in get_details %}
       {% for day in days %}
         {% if detail.teacher == teacher and detail.date|date:'d' == day %}<td>{{ detail.status }}</td>{% else %}<td>--</td>{% endif %}
       {%endfor%}
       {%endfor%}
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

one thing you must change is you need for this another format of days list
it must be [01,02,03,04, .. 10, .. 20, .. 30]

Comment: okay. but first tell me what you need to do? just show status? or you need make option to edit status?

Comment: This attendance of the teacher was submitted by a roll call of either present, absent or late on a given day, so now I want to show that status of each teacher on a specific day but days of the month should be the table head so I have to just check if day of teacher attendance  is equal to day in the table head then show status on that day, once again thank you for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206128/discussion-between-mugoya-dihfahsih-and--).

Comment: The problem am facing with the solution that you gave me is that, if the teacher made attendance of more than one, the status returned in the table is over looking and gives an overflow of table for the number of days in the month. how can I solve thi, how best can I adjust the logic in the views. Thank you

Comment: okay. lets do by this way. I cant fix your problem by rewriting your code because its very dirty code. No offense please. I can write from scratch new view for you but it will take time. For this tell which format of date you passing from template. What you are getting there `grab_data_passed = request.POST.get('group_by')`

Comment: grab_data_passed = request.POST.get('group_by') is simply getting the month that the user has selected from the dropdown menu, my code is dirty cos am still new to django

Comment: If you can please help me and restructure **views.py**

Comment: yes. but I want know which format that month will be. Maybe like '2020-01' or '2020/01/ or '01, 2020'

Comment: 01/2020 that's the format I used when inserting attendance status into the table

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to store all info in a list. For example:

```
get_all_details = list()
for i in teacher:
    x=i.id
    get_all_details.append(TeacherAttendance.objects.filter(teacher__user=x, date__month=grab_data_passed))
```

And render in template:

```
context['get_all_details']=get_all_details
```

And update the template:

```
{% for get_details in get_all_details %}
    {% for details in get_details %}
       <tr>
          <td>{{ details.teacher }}</td>
          <td>{{ details.status }}</td>
       </tr>
       {% if empty %}
        <tr>
             <td colspan="9" class="text-center bg-warning">No Data</td>
        </tr>
       {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks for that, but still have difficulty in my views

Comment: hey Rudra, any further help with a better logic in my views.py? thanks